# Android Studio: Agora SDK - Joining two Channels at the same time?

Tags: java, android, agora.io

I'm currently trying to build up a ConnectionService-Class for my Android Studio Project.

Therefore I want to join two different Channels at the same time.

This is how I made it:

```
    package com.example.test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.example.test.databinding.ActivityCommunicationBinding;

import io.agora.rtc2.ChannelMediaOptions;
import io.agora.rtc2.Constants;
import io.agora.rtc2.IAgoraEventHandler;
import io.agora.rtc2.IRtcEngineEventHandler;
import io.agora.rtc2.RtcEngine;
import io.agora.rtc2.RtcEngineConfig;

public class CommunicationService extends Service {

    private final IBinder binder = new CommunicationBinder();
    private ActivityCommunicationBinding binding;
    private Handler handler;
    private SharedPreferencesVals sharedPreferencesVals = new SharedPreferencesVals(this);
    private String accountName = "";

    private RtcEngine agoraEngineSelf;
    private RtcEngine agoraEngineAll;

    public class CommunicationBinder extends Binder {
        public CommunicationService getService() {
            return CommunicationService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sharedPreferencesVals.getAccountPreferenceVals();
        accountName = sharedPreferencesVals.accountName;
        setupAgoraEngineSelf();
        setupAgoraEngineAll();
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        joinChannels();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void setupAgoraEngineSelf() {
        try {
            RtcEngineConfig configSelf = new RtcEngineConfig();
            configSelf.mContext = getBaseContext();
            configSelf.mAppId = "HiStackOverflow";
            configSelf.mEventHandler = mRtcEventHandler;
            agoraEngineSelf = RtcEngine.create(configSelf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check the error.");
        }
    }

    private void setupAgoraEngineAll() {
        try {
            RtcEngineConfig configAll = new RtcEngineConfig();
            configAll.mContext = getBaseContext();
            configAll.mAppId = "HiStackOverflow";
            configAll.mEventHandler = mRtcEventHandler;
            agoraEngineAll = RtcEngine.create(configAll);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check the error.");
        }
    }

    private final IAgoraEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("Nutzer hinzugefügt");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("Channel " + channel + " erfolgreich beigetreten");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserOffline(int uid, int reason) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("Nutzer abgemeldet");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeaveChannel(RtcStats stats) {
            // Listen for the local user leaving the channel
        }
    };

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void joinChannels() {
        Thread threadSelf = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                joinChannelSelf();
            }
        });
        threadSelf.start();

        Thread threadAll = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                joinChannelAll();
            }
        });
        threadAll.start();

    }

    private void joinChannelSelf() {
        ChannelMediaOptions optionsSelf = new ChannelMediaOptions();
        optionsSelf.autoSubscribeAudio = true;
        optionsSelf.clientRoleType = Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER;
        optionsSelf.channelProfile = Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING;

        agoraEngineSelf.joinChannel("007eJxTYDDuPGg0932S+GTj+X3XUrcIzFtfU/g/rVFX/r33R6vtt04qMKSmGhiYWFqYWpqYWpgYGVsmGhpZGJiYWKSlmhuYGxon911fntIQyMgwrdGRgREKQXwOBq/8jMS8vNRiBgYA/XQhbA==",
                accountName, 0, optionsSelf);

    }

    private void joinChannelAll() {
        ChannelMediaOptions optionsAll = new ChannelMediaOptions();
        optionsAll.autoSubscribeAudio = true;
        optionsAll.clientRoleType = Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_AUDIENCE;
        optionsAll.channelProfile = Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING;

        agoraEngineAll.joinChannel("007eJxTYNA/ZcH/v/HhozCnFqsNzJKnzBw0Tpqpm74Uv/SKR/S38kMFhtRUAwMTSwtTSxNTCxMjY8tEQyMLAxMTi7RUcwNzQ+PkRdeXpzQEMjKYHfBiZmSAQBCfhcExJyeVgQEAsrUdIg==",
                "Alle", 0, optionsAll);

        agoraEngineAll.muteLocalAudioStream(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (agoraEngineSelf != null) {
            agoraEngineSelf.leaveChannel();
            agoraEngineSelf.destroy();
        }

        if (agoraEngineAll != null) {
            agoraEngineAll.leaveChannel();
            agoraEngineAll.destroy();
        }
    }

    public void initializePushToTalk(boolean isPushed) {
        agoraEngineAll.muteLocalAudioStream(isPushed);
    }
}
```

I think I tried everything:

- I tried calling the joinChannel-Method from the same Engine with the different Channels and Tokens.
- I tried creating two different Service-Classes to seperate everything
- and in this version I created one Service-Class but to different Engines and seperate Threads.

But it just don't works. As soon as I run the code, it connects to the first Channel "Self" without any Problems.

And inside the Terminal it also seems like it's connecting to the second Channel as well. But when I try to test it with

https://webdemo.agora.io/basicVideoCall/index.html#

there is no Audio going in or out - only in the first Channel.

So my question is:

Is there a way to connect myself to two Channels at the same time and if so, how can I do it?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am getting the same problem, the next time when I try to joinChannel, I get error -17

The error documentation says

```The request to join the channel is rejected. Typical causes include:
The user is already in the channel and still calls a method (for example, joinChannel) to join the channel. Stop calling the method to clear this error.
The user tries to join a channel during a call test. To join a channel, the call test must be ended by calling stopEchoTest.```